# PostScript code to un-hide hidden text in PDF

Tags: pdf, postscript

I have a PDF with some hidden text in it.

When I press `[CTRL+a]` I see the hidden text in my document viewer.

I can copy the text too and I can extract the text via `pdftotext`, but I can't recolorize the text so I can view the hidden text in the PDF viewer without pressing `[CTRL+a`].

So I had the idea, that I could use PostScript and change the color for the this text object.

But how can I determine what function sets the color or hides the text?

Comment: what have you tried? You should specify your attempts and problems; "how can I do this?" is not a clear question.

Comment: I have tried to export it as text. this works. but I want the hidden text in the pdffile.. so I tried to to export it as postscript file and played a bit with the values in the file. But I can't find the function that hides the text

Comment: I am looking for the name of the function who sets the color

Comment: how about editing your question to say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You cannot use PostScript to achieve what you want. You need to resort to manually editing the PDF file...***

---

There are basically three ways to "hide" text:

- It could be white (or any color) text on white (or same color as text) background.
- It could be covered by another object, say, a white area, or an image.
- It could be using *Text Rendering Mode 3* (`"3 Tr"`).

The first two cases I'll not explain here, because they are rather unlikely. For the third case you could proceed like this:

1. Use **[qpdf](http://qpdf.sf.net/)** to unpack as many as possible compressed *'streams'* inside the PDF, creating what `qpdf` calls the *'QDF mode'* of a PDF:

   ```
   qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable input.pdf uncompressed.pdf
   ```
2. Open `uncompressed.pdf` in a good text editor, such as VIm.
3. Search for the sequence `3 Tr`.
   <sub>(Text rendering mode 3 is described in the PDF-1.7 specification as *"Neither fill nor stroke text (invisible)."*)</sub>
4. Change it to `1 Tr` or `2 Tr` and save the file.
   <sub>(Text rendering mode 1 is *"stroke text"*, mode 2 is *"Fill, then stroke text." Mode 1 will only show the outlines...*)</sub>
5. Re-compress the file:

   ```
   qpdf uncompressed.pdf input-modified.pdf
   ```
6. Open the new file `input-modified.pdf` in your favourite PDF viewer. It should now show the "un-hidden" text.

---

### Update

Having received a sample of a PDF file with "hidden" text from the OP (via private channels), I can confirm now that the hiding indeed is achieved by using white text color (RGB-white).

To make such text visible:

1. Unpack the PDF, using `qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable in.pdf unpacked.pdf`
2. Search for all occurrences of `1 1 1 rg` and `1 1 1 RG`. These set the RGB colors to white (the first one *non-stroking*, the second one for *stroking* operations).
3. Comments à la `%%Contents for page N:` in the QDF-version of the uncompressed PDF file will indicate for which page the color setting is valid.  <sub>(***Note***, there may be multiple occurrences of the `rg` and `RG` operators, each one setting a different (or the same) color for the next drawing operation.)</sub>
4. Now replace the white colors by black ones, by overwriting the found occurrences with `0 0 0 rg` and `0 0 0 RG`. Do this not all at once, but one after the other and observe what changes on the respective page after saving the changes. (You may want to avoid painting white text to black if it is on a black background already!)

Comment: mhh no sorry. Seems like there is no "3 Tr" or any other "Tr" sequence in the uncompressed pdf. I used `qpdf --object-streams=disable input.pdf uncompressed.pdf`. I really think that they just used white text. Because I can see the text with `CTRL+a` ..

Comment: @Shibumi: Please, try again to uncompress it, but this time with the very same options I gave you: `qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable input.pdf uncompressed.pdf`. Without the `--qdf` option, you do ***NOT*** have un-compressed the file. -- Otherwise, please provide (a link to) a sample PDF with hidden text.

Comment: @Shibumi: When `3 Tr` is used, you can ***also*** "see" the text with `CTRL+a`...

Comment: Alternatively, as I suggested above, make the file publicly available.

Comment: Ok I tried `qpdf --qdf  --object-streams=disable testpdf.pdf uncompressed.pdf` now. But I have still no 'Tr' sequence in my pdf file.. when you are interested in the file pls follow me on twitter so I can follow back and will send you a DM

Comment: @Kurt Pfeifle

On 

5 Re-compress the file:

qpdf uncompressed.pdf input-modified.pdf

should it be
qpdf --stream-data=compress uncompressed.pdf input-modified.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, hidden text in PDF is done with a text rendering mode, not a colour. Text rendering mode 3 is 'neither stroke nor fill'. So changing the colour won't help you if this is how the text is drawn. Of course we can't tell if this is how the text has been drawn (but I suspect it is) because you haven't made the PDF file publicly available. In almost all cases if you want to discuss a particular file the best thing to do is make it public.

Secondly, you can't use PostScript to change a PDF file (well, you could write a PostScript program to interpret the PDF file, but that would be hard...)

Comment: *hidden text in PDF is done with a text rendering mode, not a colour.* - or by hiding it beneath something, e.g. a filled path or a bitmap image.

Comment: Yes, or it could be done with a colour, my point was that it 'probably' isn't, but without the file we can't tell.

Comment: but I see no `Tr` sequence in the uncompressed PDF file.. and when I mark the Text with `CTRL+a` I can see it. So I think that they just changed the text color to white..

Comment: @Shibumi: Given what command you used, quoted in the comment underneath ***my*** answer, you have ***NOT*** un-compressed the PDF file, and you therefor cannot find the `Tr` operator.

Comment: @mkl: Of course you can "hide" text ***also*** with color: by using the same background color as the text color is... It may be rather rare, but I've seen it.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle *Of course you can "hide" text also with color* - obviously... the *not a colour* in my comment was a quote from KenS' answer.